# w3wp.exe consumes a lot of memory

Tags: memory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have been watching w3wp.exe during the entire day consuming a lot of memory. As I am not good at all with windows monitoring and performance, could you please tell me how can I dig deeper to see what w3wp.exe is doing and what it is spending that amount of memory on? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: w3wp.exe = IIS. Do you host web services or develop web applications on the box?

Comment: Yes, it is a SharePoint server. Does this info help you?

Comment: look in dag logs, maybe this helps: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff463595(v=office.16).aspx